# Qt5 on MSVC2012 - moc step very slow

Tags: qt, visual-studio-2012

I have a project with a large number of MOCable header files (~350). The project so far has been using Qt4 on MSVC2012 but recently I ported it to be compatible with Qt5. Under Qt4 the moc steps would all be very quick, completing 5 or more per second. However, with Qt5 this has become very much slower - to the order of 4-5s per header file. With an otherwise parallel (multi-core) build only taking 15 or so minutes, this has tripled my rebuild time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the culprit: the qmake-generated pre-build step adds a parameter that reads an option file:

```
@path/to/mocinclude.tmp
```

This option file contains a long list of include path directives (114 in my case). I have found that for all of my MOCable headers, the code generated is exactly the same if the option file directive is skipped, plus the moc step then takes a fraction of a second.

My slightly hacky workaround is to run qmake for my project via a batch file, and add a line at the end of the batch file to overwrite the option file with a blank file, like this:

```
copy /y NUL path\to\mocinclude.opt
```

It would, however, be good to know why supplying that option file causes such a long delay for moc.